# Allow Animation to Complete Before Next Line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
 @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    animateImages()
    displayFinalOutcome()   
}
```

The problem here is that, the final outcome is displayed too quickly before the animation can finish. The animation is `UIImage.animatedImage` applied to an `Image View`.
Is there a way to delay the calling of "displayFinalOutcome" ?

I have spent no less than an hour on this. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: use handler for your animateImages() method, and in it call displayFinalOutcome() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the `displayFinalOutcome()` in `DispatchQueue` after your animation.

**Like this:**

Here `0.5` are the seconds and It can be your image animation duration.

```
@IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    animateImages()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.displayFinalOutcome()
    }      
}
```

Comment: How did you know to find this instance method under .main? I thought it would be under DispatchQueue directly...

Comment: `dispatch_async` everything that interacts with the UI must be run on the main thread. You can run other tasks that don't relate to the UI outside the main thread to increase performance.

Comment: Sorry again, why is there no "execute:" after the "deadline:"?

Answer (score 1):

Better to use handlers, I think. Like this:

```
@IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        animateImages { (complete) in
            displayFinalOutcome()
        }
    }

    func animateImages(completion: ((Bool) -> ())) {
        // code of your method
        completion(true)
    }
```

**Update**
example inside animateImages() method:

```
func animateImages(completion: ((Bool) -> ())) {
    // code of your method
    UIView.animate(withDuration: yourTimeInterval, animations: {
        // code of your animations
    }) { (complete) in
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

Here your method displayFinalOutcome() can be applying only after your animation complete

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        animateImages()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { // change 2 to desired number of seconds
       // Your code with delay
         self.displayFinalOutcome()   
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help.